# Angular - returning promise.then from function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

I have never looked at angular before and I am working on a project that uses it extensively, I am quite confused by the promise api code.

If a function returns promise.then (which I gather is called when the promise is fulfilled) is this the result of the promise function? Is there any blocking when you do this as the result isnt immediately available?

A crude example:

```
$scope.refreshFilters = function (filters) {
    var promise;
    promise = getConfig(filters);
    return promise.then(function (data) {
        return data.availableContent;
    });
};
```

Do calls to the refreshFilters function need to block now because the result isnt available immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, `promise.then(...)` itself returns a promise. You can find the Promise A+ spec, which $q mostly follows here: https://promisesaplus.com/

A promise is a way of handling asynchronous work. In your example, `getConfig(filters)` returns a promise, which is handled with the `.then(...)` call. And `refreshFilters` returns a promise because `getConfig(filters).then(...)` also returns a promise. If `getConfig` executes asynchronously, then `refreshFilters` will as well.

Answer (score 2):

The return inside the "then" returns a promise not the plain value,
so

```
return promise.then(function (data) {                    
                return data.availableContent;
            });
};
```

is actually returning a promise.

Comment: ... which resolves to the value returned by the function supplied to `then()`